# Showing Django Login Modal Form Error

Tags: jquery, python, django, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to display an error in the modal instead of redirecting to /accounts/login when a user submits an incorrect login form.

basic.html where the login modal appears

```
...
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" id="login_modal_trigger">Log In</button>

{% include 'registration/login.html' with form=form %}
...
```

registration/login.html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Log In</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div id="content-container" class="container p-none">
            <div class="lgn-container col-lg-8">
                <form id="login-form" method="post"
                      action="{% url 'login' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="id_username">Username</label></td>
                            <td><input id="id_username" name="username"
                                       type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="id_password">Password</label></td>
                            <td><input id="id_password" name="password"
                                       type="password" class="form-control"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    {% if form.errors %}
                        <p class=" label label-danger">
                            Your username and password didn't match.
                            Please try again.
                        </p>
                    {% endif %}

                    <input type="submit" id="ajax_form_submit" value="Login"
                           class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
<!-- I comment the next line to allow the LOGIN_REDERICT_URL in project/settings.py to work. -->
                    <!-- <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" /> -->
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

script.js:
I figured `event.preventDefault();` would prevent redirecting when there is an error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var frm = $('#login_form');
$('#loginModal').click("#ajax_form_submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        // $('#login_form').ajax_form(target:'#login_form').submit();
        $.ajax({//begin
        type: 'POST',
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: $(frm).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $(frm).hide();
    $("#div-form").html("<h3 style='text-align:center;'>Thank you, for Registering!</h3>");

        },
        error: function(data) {
            $("#div-form").html("Failure!");
        }//end error
    });//end ajax
    });
});
```

project/settings.py

```
...
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/app/login_success/'
...
```

project/urls.py

```
...
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    ...
]
...
```

app/urls.py

```
...
app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^login_success/$', views.login_success, name='login_success'), # redirect to user profile
    ...
]
...
```

The login modal works, but it redirects to the /accounts/login url if there is an error instead of displaying error messages in the modal. The js I use is mostly from other posts.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the server returns a 200 http response. In order to enter in the error section of your AJAX code you have to return an error like the 401 or similar (check the error you need). For example: return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=401).
There are some libreries like intercooler.js which send AJAX requests with HTML tags, like `<form ic-post-to="{% url 'login' %}" ic-target="$('#div-form')">` ... This is the same that all your code.

In order to respond to your last comment, I have never used the general views. I give to you a snippet of my code:

**views.py**

```
def iniciarSesion(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    loginForm = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if loginForm.is_valid():
        acceso = authenticate(username=loginForm.cleaned_data['username'], password=loginForm.cleaned_data['password'])
        if acceso is not None and acceso.is_active:
            login(request, acceso)
            return HttpResponse('')
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'password':'El usuario o contraseña son incorrectos'}, status=401)
    else:
        return JsonResponse(loginForm.errors, status=400)
```

**forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
username = forms.CharField(max_length=60, label=u'Usuario')
password = forms.CharField(max_length=32, label=u'Contraseña')
```

And that's all. To do AJAX request I actually use this library http://intercoolerjs.org/docs.html, it's better than write your own AJAX code redundant all time for each request. But of course, you can use AJAX whatever you want, without extra libraries.

Comment: is there a way to do this without additional libraries?

Comment: also, I'm just using Django's default login view, so do I need to rewrite it to return JsonResponses instead of whatever it currently does?